# Given $\lim_n a_n = 0$, then $\lim_n r a_n = 0 \quad \forall r\in \mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis

> Given $\lim_n a_n = 0$ then $\lim_n r a_n = 0 \quad \forall r\in \mathbb{R}$?

I think it is true, then does it follow that for each $f\in C([0,1])$, we have 
$$\lim_n \int_0^1 f(x)\sin(nx) \; dx= 0$$
from $f$ is bounded $|f|\leq M$, and $\lim_n \int_0^1 \sin(nx)\;dx= 0$.

Someone said the above argument is wrong, but I can't quite see the mistake :(

Thank you very much!

Comment: What *is* the argument, anyway?

Comment: To show $ \lim_n\int_0^1 f(x)\sin(nx) = 0 $ from $$   0 = -M\lim_n\int_0^1 \sin(nx) \; dx\leq  \lim_n\int_0^1 f(x)\sin(nx) \; dx  \leq M\lim_n\int_0^1 \sin(nx) \; dx = 0$$

Answer (score 1):

It is true if you fix a $r\in \mathbb{R}$ (It is a basic exercise in mathematical analysis, you can use $\varepsilon-\delta$ expression to prove it).

To your "argument", I think it has nothing to do with your proposition. And for $f\in C_{0}[0,1]$ such that 
$$ \lim_n \int_0^1 \sin(nx)\;dx= 0$$
then, as you mentioned,
 $$ 0=-M\lim_n \int_0^1 \sin(nx)\;dx\leq \lim_n \int_0^1 f(x)\sin(nx)\;dx\leq M\lim_n \int_0^1 \sin(nx)\;dx= 0.$$